# Why was my edit marked "deliberately destructive"?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I edited this question today ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20419951)) and it was rejected with the reason:

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service,
>   or is deliberately destructive.

I didn't change any of the meaning of the question (at least I believe I didn't), and what I thought was increasing clarity by correcting grammar and reformatting code.

**My question is:** Why was my edit marked "deliberately destructive", and how can I improve my editing in future?

[image: edit]

Comment: The reviewers didn't pay attention. Your edit is really good and I encourage you to keep it up!

Comment: This edit right here will make a good audit

Comment: You could have added more details on the edit summary, like "Organic title" and "Removed unrelated text". I'm not familiar with Excel VBA and that code formatting that you applied on the example seems weird, could have been explained on the summary as well. . . [&](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good,_the_Bad_and_the_Ugly) yeah, bad reviewers, good edit

Comment: Note that the edit was rejected by only one user, the OP. As explained in the linked question, OP has the power to reject the edit for any reason. I can’t speculate why *your* OP did so, but your edit was solid. Nice job.

Comment: Ahhh, OP rejected, so now I'll speculate they didn't like removing "Help me" \o/

Comment: Thanks all, I'll keep fighting the good fight. Will also keep in mind adding detail to the comment to explain my changes better.